unable to retrive the data from database using servlets
I created a Java Dynamic Project using ecllipse with Servlets, JSP and Mysql where i tried to retrive the data from database but while running it getting the below error.
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /designers.jsp at line 17

14: <body>
15:     <div class="portfolio-grid">
16: <%--    <% if (designers != null && !designers.isEmpty()) { %> --%>
17:         <% for (Designer designer : designers) { %>
18:         <div class="profile-card">
19:             <!-- Image as a clickable link -->
20:             <a href="<%= designer.getProfileLink() %>" target="_blank"> <img


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.designers_jsp._jspService(designers_jsp.java:82)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

DesignerServlet
package com.portfolio.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.portfolio.model.Designer;

public class DesignerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("DEBUGG: Inside the goGet Method");
        List<Designer> designers = new ArrayList<Designer>();

        try {
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/PortfolioDB", "root", "nidroot");
            System.out.println("Connected successfully!");

            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM designers");

            System.out.println("Fetching data from database...");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Processing record...");
                Designer designer = new Designer();
                designer.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                designer.setDegree(rs.getString("degree"));
                designer.setSpecialization(rs.getString("specialization"));
                designer.setKeywords(rs.getString("keywords"));
                designer.setImagePath(rs.getString("imagePath"));
                designer.setProfileLink(rs.getString("profileLink"));
                designers.add(designer);
            }

            System.out.println("Data fetching completed. Total designers: " + designers.size());

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("DEBUGG: SQL Exception: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        request.setAttribute("designers", designers);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("designers.jsp").forward(request, response);

        System.out.println("DEBUGG: Exiting the doGet Method");
    }
}

designers.jsp
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="com.portfolio.model.Designer"%>
<%
    
    List<Designer> designers = (List<Designer>) request.getAttribute("designers");
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Portfolio Portal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="portfolio-grid">
<%--    <% if (designers != null && !designers.isEmpty()) { %> --%>
        <% for (Designer designer : designers) { %>
        <div class="profile-card">
            <!-- Image as a clickable link -->
            <a href="<%= designer.getProfileLink() %>" target="_blank"> <img
                src="<%= designer.getImagePath() %>" alt="<%= designer.getName() %>"
                class="profile-image">
            </a>
            <h3><%= designer.getName() %></h3>
            <p>
                <strong><%= designer.getDegree() %></strong>
            </p>
            <p><%= designer.getSpecialization() %></p>
            <p><%= designer.getKeywords() %></p>
        </div>
        <% } %>
<%--        <% } else { %>
             <p>No designer profiles available.</p>
         <% } %>  --%>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


I debuged the but unable to find the reason for null pointer exception. Provide the solution for it.
thank you

In your web browser, you need to hit the URL of the Servlet instead of the URL of the JSP. See abovelinked duplicates to get started.

When working with JSP, if you want to use it as a View for a Controller, you need to initialize variables inside the controller itself and don't call JSP directly. The error is displayed in the console. You can easily figure out the initialized variable by the line number.
